# Can a cylindrical chamber geared into a larger one on the outside decrease the size need for artificial gravity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames, centrifugal-force

I’m designing a interplanetary ship and I’m trying to figure out how to fix the large size required for a ship with artificial gravity given budget. My question is if there was a main cylindrical body of a space ship which was spinning at x1 velocity and inside that was another cylindrical chamber geared into it being spun at x1 by the outer cylinder. Could the inside chamber be spun more by gearing it in on the inside of the main chamber to a motor of sorts? Basically it would be spinning by X1 plus the more rotation that x2 would spin it. I’m hoping this might reduce the requirements of such a large ship. This could be completely wrong I’m just wondering is it and if so could someone point me in the right direction.

Basically to the inside chamber it’s like it’s only spinning x2 but from POV of outer space it’s spinning X1 and X2 because it’s being rotated by the outside cylindrical body 1X and a motor spinning itself x2.

[image: sorry for my terrible drawing skills did my best]

Comment: It's not clear to me what problem you're expecting this to solve. What do you mean by "decrease the size need for artificial gravity"?

Comment: @Ajedi32 I mean currently it’s said that you need a massive wheel to make a proper gravity wheel that doesn’t cause blood rushing to the feet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this, although it may actually make it harder to develop such a ship rather than easier.

The key equation is the equation for [centripetal acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centripetal_force): $a_c=r\omega^2$, where $r$ is the radius of the rotation and $\omega$ is the angular velocity (how fast it is spinning).  There's a few variants of that (some use velocity rather than angular velocity), but this one is in a convenient form to see what matters here.

If you create a smaller inner rotation, you inherently decrease the centripetal acceleration at the same angular velocity, and thus are forced to spin it faster to achieve the same pseudo-gravity.  So you have to watch out for that.

Your approach would be useful in situations where you had a reason to keep the outside "spun down."  Perhaps you were looking to observe the stars.  However, the price you pay is the coupling.  That gear train your describe is a mechanical linkage that has to operate very reliably for very long amounts of time.  It may be easier to simply spin up the whole craft, just to avoid such mechanics.  You might need exotic tricks to minimize wear, like [magnetic gears](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_gear).

In general, its easier to spin up the craft because you can use thrusters to do so.  However, what you describe is really just a twisted version of [reaction wheels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reaction_wheel), which are used on many spacecraft like the ISS to control orientation.  So in that sense it works.

I would be careful making the inner cylinder too small.  One of the major reasons to make these rings big is that the human brain is not used to rotating frames.  That's why happy-go-pukey rides like the Tilt-a-wheel are such a thrill.  In particular, the [Coriolis effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coriolis_force) really messes with our brains.  If we make the rings large, we can achieve the same pseudogravity with a smaller angular rate, which is better for our minds.

I don't have the book on hand, but Rendezvous with Rama, by Arthur C. Clarke, had a brilliant example of this.  In that book, there is a 1km diameter cylinder.  You dock in the center, and walk down a spiral staircase to the bottom.  In the book they describe it as a treacherous descent.  It seems so easy at first in the low pseudogravity that you might try skipping a step or two to speed the climb down to the bottom.  But one had to constantly remember that the stairs were rotating away from you.  One misstep and you may float away from the stairs, unable to stop until colliding with the spinning surface 1km below.

Comment: About ascending and descending in a kilometer-scale rotating spacestation: there is an idea for a running gag that I would love to pitch to Seth McFarlane. There is this spacestation, and it has wicked fast elevators. As you enter  you need to position yourself against a sidewall of the elevator cabin. As the cabin ascends/descends the change--of-radial-distance effect slams your back against the wall. Crew members entering an elevator are always bickering, arguing *which wall* they need to position against. And then they pick the wrong wall every. single. time.

Answer (score 0):

Can you have in inside cylinder spinning at a faster rate than $x_1$? Yes, you can. Any sort of gear train connecting the two cylinders can enforce higher or lower (or reverse) speeds as seen from an outside observer.

Will this affect the artificial gravity? I doubt it. Do the math model for the $g$ forces due to spinning you you find $g = R_1 x_1^2$ and in no part what the rest of the ship is doing matters.

You can however use the inside cylinder as a flywheel to spin up the overall rotation after launch which will reduce the fuel requirements at launch.